# need help w? Samsung ML-2545 printer on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, samsung

I have a Samsung ML-2545 printer and cannot find a driver that can load.. Is there a driver that will load without special code? I am on 12.1

Answer (score 0):

1 - Download the [Unified Linux Driver](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/supportUsefulSwPrinter.do)

2 - Open Terminal, Copy & Paste.

`sudo sh install.sh`

Press Enter & enter your password.

Now the installation starts. Answer the questions (**choose to disable printing from the LTP port: that's outdated**).